# Removing two closest table rows with jQuery

Tags: jquery, closest

```
$('table#Items').on('click','tr input#delItem',function(e){
    $(this).closest('tr').remove();
});
```

Hi all. Please tell me, what is the right solution for removing two table rows in lieu of one? Thank you

Comment: lieu of one..? what does that mean.?

Comment: I think it's the same as instead of

Comment: do you mean the closest tr and the next tr

Comment: may be `$(this).closest('tr').next().addBack().remove();`

Comment: Yes, two table rows closest to selector.

Comment: can you share the table sample

Comment: Are you trying to delete the tr that you are clicking or some other tr?  I ask because if you are doing $(this).closest('tr').remove(), and based on the selector you've provided it's going to remove the row you're on.

Comment: `$(this).closest('body').remove()` should solve all your worries until you can properly explain what the "two closest" table rows are.

Comment: add the same class to both and remove?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The following code will remove the next and the previous row from the closest row.

Try,

```
$('table#Items').on('click','tr input#delItem',function(e){
    var closestRow = $(this).closest('tr');
    closestRow.add(closestRow.prev()).add(closestRow.next()).remove();
});
```

Comment: This is what I need, thank you. I'll accept once I'll be able.

Comment: Actually I needed the following `var closestRow = $(this).closest('tr');
    closestRow.add(closestRow.prev()).add(closestRow.prev()).remove();`, but you gave me the solution

Answer (score 3):

Here is an example: http://jqversion.com/#!/72F15CA/1

```
$('table#Items').on('click','tr input#delItem', function(e){

    $(this).closest('tr').nextAll().slice(0,2).remove();
});
```